# error from glmer in R

Tags: r, mixed-models

When I run a glmer analysis in R:

```
datglmer = glmer(word ~ lg + age_b + (1|name), data=dat, family=binomial)
```

I get:

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
```

The data in table format are:

```
> table(dat$word, dat$lg, dat$age_b)
, ,  = adu
           lw   w
  boy      66   0
  wirriya   3  63

, ,  = chn
           lw   w
  boy     110   0
  wirriya  35  89
```

The item 'boy' doesn't occur in the predictor 'w'. Is there a way to run this analysis?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a reproducible example to make it easier for people to help

Comment: Does it work if name is a fixed effect instead of random?

Comment: The data are available here: https://mfile.umich.edu/?path=/afs/umich.edu/user/c/a/carmelos/Public/data/StatsPrepWirriya_Boy.txt

Comment: (1) that URL requires a password. (2) an additive model for the fixed effects should work just fine.  (3) the warning messages in `glmer` tend to produce false positive convergence, especially for large data: see `?convergence` in the latest (1.1-8) lme4 release

Comment: See related answer on Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242109/model-failed-to-converge-warning-in-lmer